# weexのiOSで日本語のテキストを表示すると、テキストの下に余白ができる

Tags: javascript, vue.js

weexでアプリを作成しています。
iOSで日本語のテキストを表示すると、テキストの下に余白ができてしまいます。
WebやAndroidでの表示では問題ありません。
下記のデモをiOSのweex playgroundで見るとキャプチャのようにテキストの下に余白ができ、
英語と日本語のテキストを併記した場合にunderlineもずれてしまいます。（キャプチャ参照）

デモ：
http://dotwe.org/vue/8180c47f84522b0466e3e78d412283b0

どなたか解決策をご存知の方はいませんでしょうか。

[image]

Answer (score 1):

デフォルトのweexの指定fontだと中国語フォントになっているようです。
なのでiOSの場合、元からiPhoneに入っているフォントである「Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN」を
cssのfont-familyで指定してあげるとうまく表示されました。

以下サンプルコードです。

```
 .クラス名 {
  　　 font-family: Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN;
 }
```

Comment: （2）は解決されますが、
（1）の天地中央にならない問題は解決されません